# Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: food (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM food order by id asc

Tags: java, android-studio

I am getting this error in the Logcat when I compiled the program.

according to the Logcat, these are the two places that causing the error
[image]
[image]

I have tried everything to solve but none of it works.

please help to solve.

here are the 2 java class i created
   1st java class [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I22iZ.png)
   next part  [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aylqN.png)

2nd java class [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpnE8.png)
      next part   [6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkD3e.png)

Comment: Make sure you have a table called "food" in your database

Comment: there is a table called food in the database

Comment: can you show the create table query is there id present? and you have not open db object in readable to get data

Comment: here are the 2 java class file i created